# Find the supremum of $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis

Essentially I'm trying to prove that the supremum of $1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ is $1$. This makes sense since $1 \geq 1-\frac{1}{2^n}$ for every n in N, so $1$ is an upper bound. However, I'm not sure how to show that $1$ is the least upper bound and that all the other upper bounds are less than or equal to $1$. I've done similar problems where the supremum is also maximum, but in this case it is not. Can anyone give me a hint as to how to prove this?

Comment: Hint, assume that the supremum is $1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Can you come to a contradiction? Depending on where to start, one can note that $1/2^n$ contains arbitrarily small numbers.

Comment: Hint: $1/2^n$ is always positive but can get arbitrarily close to 0

Answer (score 1):

If $0<x < 1$, you have to find an $n$ such that : $1-\dfrac{1}{2^n} > x\iff 1-x > \dfrac{1}{2^n}\iff 2^n >\dfrac{1}{1-x}$, and this is achievable since $2^n \to +\infty$, thus there must be an $N_0$ such that: $2^{N_0} > \dfrac{1}{1-x}$. Now for if $y$ is an upper bound, you need to show $y \geq 1$, but this means $y \geq 1-\dfrac{1}{2^n}$,for all $n$, taking limit we have $y \geq 1$. Done.